# Compiling QEMU with SPICE support

Tags: qemu

I am trying to compile QEMU 1.3 with [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) with [SPICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE_(protocol)) enabled, but I get this error:

```
ERROR
ERROR: User requested feature spice
ERROR: configure was not able to find it
ERROR
```

I have read around, and it seems I should edit the pkg configuration path. I am running Ubuntu, and I tried changing the pkg configuration, but I am guessing...help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `spice-protocol` first. Unfortunately (atleast on 12.10) it is not available in the main repositories, so you will have to [download](http://spice-space.org/download.html) and compile it:

```
wget http://spice-space.org/download/releases/spice-protocol-0.12.3.tar.bz2
tar -xjf spice-protocol-0.12.3.tar.bz2
cd spice-protocol*
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

If you prefer you can use git:

```
git clone git://git.freedesktop.org/git/spice/spice-protocol
```

If you have `build-essentail` installed, the compilation should go without any problem.

After this just proceed to the compilation of qemu enabling spice, passing `--enable-spice` to configure:

```
./configure --enable-spice
# make & make install
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have both installed spice-protocol and spice server:

pkg-config spice-protocol --modversion
0.12.3
pkg-config spice-server --modversion
0.12.2

Comment: what is the output of `pkg-config --cflags spice-protocol spice-server`?

Comment: I didn't have the latest spice, so I installed it and now it is working

Comment: @user1640204 If this solved your problem please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3):

Now(2021) there exist spice packages for Ubuntu.
Use these

```
sudo apt install libspice-protocol-dev
sudo apt install libspice-server-dev
```

Remember to configure qemu with --enable-spice.

For reference these are the spice related packages I have.

```
username@username-H81 ~/b/q/qemu (master)> apt list --installed | grep spice

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libspice-client-glib-2.0-8/groovy,now 0.38-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libspice-client-gtk-3.0-5/groovy,now 0.38-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libspice-protocol-dev/groovy,groovy,now 0.14.1-2 all [installed]
libspice-server-dev/groovy,now 0.14.3-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
libspice-server1/groovy,now 0.14.3-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
spice-client-glib-usb-acl-helper/groovy,now 0.38-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
spice-client-gtk/groovy,now 0.38-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
spice-vdagent/groovy-security,groovy-updates,now 0.20.0-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
spice-webdavd/groovy,now 2.5-1 amd64 [installed]
```